# How to tell which class owns a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I was watching a vid about smart pointers (vid link below), which identifies the following problem with traditional C++ pointers:

**You can't tell who owns the pointer**

Hebert goes on to give the following example: Class A has a pointer to a float, class B has a pointer to that same float. Which of the two owns the pointer? Well, you can't tell... it's not clear... we don't know whose job it is do delete the pointer.. .bad.. convoluted.. hard to debug.

What the heck is he talking about? How are we not able tell which class owns the pointer? If the pointer is created as part of class A or B's instance, then would it not simply be A->myPointer, and B->myPointer, respectively?

Thx :^) Keith

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jc9n9BcYSj4
At about 1:00

## EDIT

```
#include <iostream>
class A {
public: float * f_ptr;
};
class B {
public: float * f_ptr;
};
int main() {
    float f=2.71;
    A* a = new(A);
    B* b = new(B);
    a->f_ptr = &f;
    b->f_ptr = &f;
    std::cout << "a->f_ptr: " << *a->f_ptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b->f_ptr: " << *b->f_ptr << std::endl;
    delete a;
    delete b;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

/************
OUTPUT

a->f_ptr: 2.71
b->f_ptr: 2.71

*/
```

## EDIT 2

The following post explains this phenomenon very well:
http://ericlavesson.blogspot.com/2013/03/c-ownership-semantics.html

Comment: They mean the thing the pointer points to. And I guess it assumes somebody other than the pointed to object itself owns it.

Comment: raw pointer can only have one owner, so who is the owner? A or B?

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that one of the classes should delete the pointer, but not before the other class has stopped using it. How do we know? A smart pointer could figure that out.

Comment: @BryanChen Doesn't have to be either.

Comment: A raw pointer without owner means memory leak, which class is responsible to delete it?

Comment: What do you mean by " then would it not simply be A->myPointer, and B->myPointer, respectively?" Would be what, for whom?

Comment: This problem refers to the scenario where `A->myPointer` and `B->myPointer` both point to the same instance. Who deletes it? A's destructor or B's destructor? How do you know the other instance(s) have already been destroyed? One of those pointers should be the 'owning' one, but tracking that can be tricky sometimes without smart pointers.

Comment: @BryanChen No, pointers don't have to point to things that need to be freed.

Comment: If we delete A before B, B must delete the pointer. If we don't know whether A or B will be deleted first, the pointer must be shared - the last to delete must delete the pointer. C++ unique and shared pointers make that explicit, with plain pointers you rely upon the discipline of the programmer.

Comment: That will make it much less useful and most of the pointers are point to dynamic allocated memory. Which I assume is this question about.

Comment: @BryanChen Do you have some stats to back that up? Have you read all the programs?

Comment: The world will be a much better place if we know a way to avoid dynamic memory allocation in C++ without reduce productivity and increase learning barrier.

Comment: So, I've tried to create a case where this pointer confusion exists... see "EDIT" section in question above. I still do not understand where the ownership problem lies. Both pointers are separately deleted byt the ``delete a`` and ``delete b`` commands. This compiles and runs without error.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN the deletes are fine because they are deleting `a` and `b` which were created with `new`. That said they aren't necessary as `a` and `b` can be created automatically instead of dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When he says that some class "owns the pointer", that means that this class is responsible for cleaning up the mess the pointer does. You can have two different classes A and B that use a pointer that points to the same object. Unless you are the designer of these classes, you can't tell which one should delete the object in the end and do the cleaning after it, e.g. unlocking some resources. You can't figure that out or set it by using some built-in language semantics - you have to be told about it, e.g. via documentation. If the design is bad, you may end up with two classes trying to clean after the same object twice or not cleaning up after the object at all.

Technically it's about who owns the memory that the pointer points to, not about the pointers themselves, but most people refer to the problem I have described above while talking about owning a pointer.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the scenario discussed in the video. This question obviously has far-reaching implications, and can branch off into many different discussions, but your response answered my question.

Comment: No problem. Glad that I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Good or bad, but C and C++ languages do not establish any rules on the ownership on the memory that the pointers are pointing to. This has very far-reaching consequences. As of today it is too late to establish any rules here. Tons and tons of existing code will be broken.

It is possible to decide on the application level who owns the pointer and who just uses it. But this will be decision of the application programmer, not the rules of the language. And this decision should be documented (typically using comments) and communicated to people who will continue working on this code.

Some think that explicit ownership is a bad practice and smart pointers are the right way to go. Some think that patterns with explicit ownership are still ok.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between the pointer itself (an address) and the memory that is pointed to.

Each class owns its pointer, but nobody technically owns the pointed memory. It 
has to be managed somehow (if it's unallocated, it's a segfault; if it's deallocated twice, it's a double free; and if it's not deallocated at all it's a memory leak) but that's purely dependent on the programmer. One may make a class responsible for some memory (by having the constructor and destructor of this class manage it) but that's purely a convention, not a language feature. Other classes are not going to be denied the right to free or reallocate this memory if they're given a copy of the address/pointer (though it would usually be a very bad idea).

Answer (score 1):

Smart pointers are seldom a solution to the stated problem. They are often a solution to another problem, though.

The problem outlined here is a problem of a shared ownership. When both `A` and `B` 'own' the resource, who is responsible for freeing it? `std::shared_pointer` is a reference-counting pointer, which would free the resource once all the users of it has gone away. However, this scenario should be avoided. Having shared pointers in the program makes it extremely difficult to argue about life time of the resource. Although there are few cases when using `shared_pointer` (usually a case with multithreaded queues), it is better to try hard to avoid shared ownership - as in real life, by the way :). Instead, make one class an owner and another one a user, and design your interface in such a way that users never outlive the owners. It is not as hard as it might seem, and this design will pay back in easier program maintenance.

Once you have identified the owner, than `std::unique_ptr` is a way to go. It gives you worry-free life-time of the pointer equal to the life-time of the parent object, prevents dangerous copying-assigning, and is exception safe.